# (JavaScript) How do you return all objects in an array as a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Essentially, I want to use an array as my list of arguments. However, the function has an argument called ranges: [ ], and the list of my specific ranges should go in there.

My code looks like:

```
  var args = new Array();

  args.push({ color: '#c1f5b0', start: 0, length: 5 })
  args.push({ color: '#c1f5b0', start: 6, length: 5 })

   $('#demo').someFunc({
      ranges: [
        //list of objects goes here
      ]
  });
```

Basically, I want the list of objects to print as args[0], args[1]. Obviously, putting the syntax `args[0], args[1]` into the range gives the behaviour I want. But it won't always be necessarily two elements in the array. I tried putting `args.join()` but that just returns the array contents as a string. Using simply `args` in `console.log(args)` gives exactly the behaviour I want, but I can't reproduce that behaviour inside the `ranges: [ ] code`.

Comment: Not sure I follow... Have you tried `concat`?

Comment: @elclanrs That doesn't work either sadly. :(

Comment: UM, how about just  `{ranges:args}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we get started, remember than JS lists and arrays are the same thing.

If you want to call a function using an array of arguments:

```
someFunc.apply($('#demo'), args);
```

If you want to take part of the `args` array:

```
someFunc({ranges: args.slice(0, 10)});
```

If you want to explode the array into arguments, with ES6:

```
someFunc({ranges: [...args]});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass your array as the value of the 'ranges' parameter.  You do not need to create a new array literal.

```
$('#demo').someFunc({
    ranges: args
});
```

Comment: Oh this worked perfectly. I feel like such a fool now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```js
$('#demo').someFunc({
  ranges: args
});
```